# WSOD 3.9.1 – Tried Everything so far

Tags: database, site-url, fatal-error

Hoping someone can help me troubleshoot my White Screen of Death.

Site Info:

- WP 3.9.1 (just upgraded)
- PHP Version: 5.4 (just upgraded)
- Single Version
- Many other installs of WP on this server (with same database / php settings) and they are unaffected.
- I was prompted to do the 'Update Database Required' on wp-admin when I first had the issue and I did.
- I CAN log into wp-admin and content is there in the backend working fine with no issue
- All Plugins disabled.

What I've done so far:

1. Check version with version.php and database values

   - wp_db_version = 27916 (matches database)
   - Also checked 'home' and 'siturl' to see if they have the correct url—they do
2. Disabled plugins (renamed plugins folder to plugins.hold)

   - After renaming this the site generated a code about wp-super-cache error
   - After error, I added a new plugins folder > and downloaded most recent version of the plugin  and installed manually
   - Error message went away, but still WSOD no html generated
   - I set the 'active_plugins' value to 'a:0:{}' in database
3. Deleted custom theme, should be referencing twentyfourteen
4. Manually replaced wordpress base files
5. Tried error reporting on wp-config—no reports generated, still WSOD

I'm out of ideas, don't know what else to even search for—and since I can't get error reporting to show anything, I'm at a roadblock.

Comment: white screens of death are when error reporting is not set to display errors. Find your error log or enable error reporting

Comment: When you say "should be referencing twentyfourteen", did you actually activate it in the admin? Otherwise WP will just bail on the front-end if the active theme isn't there.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic please add this as an answer so you get some points. And send me your address—you get a box of cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to activate the default theme in the admin; WordPress will just bail on the front-end if the active theme isn't on the filesystem (it won't fallback to the default automatically).

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

- increasing the memory limit? http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Increasing_memory_allocated_to_PHP
- PHP error reporting? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575482/how-do-i-enable-error-reporting-in-php

Comment: Thanks, I've now tried increasing the limit—no avail. I've emailed the hosting company about whether or not there is a block / set value on the server for PHP Memory Limit as I cannot find it in the CPanel.

Comment: Where do you suggest adding the PHP error reporting code on the link you provided? Tried a few places like root index file—no luck.

Comment: add it in wp-config.php, right before it says to stop editing